# Expected 'End' to match 'IF' at character 0

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBA8D.png)

Whats is the issue with my calculated field here? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Wrong type of closing brace for [SEM Cost] after the third THEN

You could simplify by combining the second and third cases since they lead to the same result, and could also remove some unnecessary parentheses

Comment: I am not receiving "Reference to undefined field"

Comment: @seth So? The error message doesn't always get the right error and the bracket is clearly an error.